# Filter content with jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, function, filter

I have a basic filter in HTML and jQuery. It works fine, however when you unchecked all filter options it shows no result.

What I'm trying to achieve is when all the options are unchecked, it shows all the results by default.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.tags').find('input:checkbox').on('click', function() {
    $('.results > li').hide();
    $('div.tags').find('input:checked').each(function() {
      $('.results > li.' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tags">
  <label>
        <input type="checkbox" rel="arts" />
        Arts
    </label>
  <label>
        <input type="checkbox" rel="computers" />
        Computers
    </label>
  <label>
        <input type="checkbox" rel="health" />
        Health
    </label>
  <label>
        <input type="checkbox" rel="video-games" />
        Video Games
    </label>
</div>

<ul class="results">
  <li class="arts computers">Result 1</li>
  <li class="video-games">Result 2</li>
  <li class="computers health video-games">Result 3</li>
  <li class="arts video-games">Result 4</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an if/else statement to check if any checkbox is checked. If not show all results.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //We want to show all when all checkboxes are unchecked, which is default, so this is not needed.
  //$('.results > li').hide();

  $('div.tags').find('input:checkbox').on('click', function() {
    $('.results > li').hide();

    let $checkedInputs = $('div.tags').find('input:checked');
    if ($checkedInputs.length) {
      $checkedInputs.each(function() {
        $('.results > li.' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();
      });
    } else {
      $('.results > li').show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tags">
  <label>
        <input type="checkbox" rel="arts" />
        Arts
    </label>
  <label>
        <input type="checkbox" rel="computers" />
        Computers
    </label>
  <label>
        <input type="checkbox" rel="health" />
        Health
    </label>
  <label>
        <input type="checkbox" rel="video-games" />
        Video Games
    </label>
</div>

<ul class="results">
  <li class="arts computers">Result 1</li>
  <li class="video-games">Result 2</li>
  <li class="computers health video-games">Result 3</li>
  <li class="arts video-games">Result 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Mark. I also tried a if/else statement but I didn't find the way how to detect when all the options are unchecked. Anyway thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```js
filter();

$(document).on('change', '.tags input', filter);

function filter(){
  const filterValues = [];
  $('.tags input').each(function(){
    if($(this).prop('checked')){
      filterValues.push($(this).val())
    }
  })
  if(!filterValues.length){
    $('.results li').show();
    return;
  }
  $('.results li').each(function(){
    const li = $(this);
    let classNames = li.attr('class');
    if(!classNames) return;
    classNames = classNames.split(' ');
    let isShow = false;
    classNames.forEach(className => {
      if(filterValues.includes(className)){
        isShow = true;
        return false;
      }
    })
    if(isShow){
      li.show();
    }else{
      li.hide();
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tags">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="arts">
        Arts
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="computers">
        Computers
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="health">
        Health
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="video-games">
        Video Games
    </label>
</div>

<ul class="results">
    <li class="arts computers">Result 1
    <li class="video-games">Result 2
    <li class="computers health video-games">Result 3
    <li class="arts video-games">Result 4
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @imhvost. Your solution is really good too and works like a charm.

Comment: @Mathieu Préaud, Happy to help 